# Access internal MSSQL database with php/laravel

Tags: php, sql-server

I make a small php-website for a company and have to access the internal MSSQL database. The sqlsrv driver for php are installed. I can connect in the internal network structure to the Database.

The network structure looks like this:

Internet ---> Firewall ---> Server Farm(in this server farm)

1. Server1: WinGate Proxy Server
2. Server2: MSSQL
3. Server3: Print Server
4. Server4: Exchange Server
5. Server5: Domaincontroller1
6. Server6: Domaincontroller2
   [image]

I hope i made a good to understand template. Everthing is working on Windows. There is a static ip.
What is the best way to access the database with php ? Can i access it remotely ? What is the best practice for this problem.

Comment: Define "remotely" - where is the PHP application located?  Have you actually tried to connect to it? Wherever you're connecting from, the correct ports have to be open between the source and destination. You can read on MSDN what ports you need. I'm not a network administrator, but I would strongly advise against, for instance, opening the SQL Server ports to the wider internet, unless you know exactly what you're doing (e.g. you're Microsoft running an Azure DB-as-a-service!). Normal convention if you have an app that needs access to a DB via the internet is to put a web API in between.

Comment: For efficiency, it surely would be most suitable to have a webserver within your server farm and host the PHP application there, then there's no problem with access to the DB from the PHP server.

Comment: Thank you for the information. So the best way is to make a REST API and connect it to the web application ?

Comment: Well I think the simplest way is to host the application on a server in your farm. But if you absolutely must host it somewhere outside that network, then the most secure way is to have an API which is hosted within the network and accessible from outside it, yes. Assuming it's written correctly, it'll be more secure then exposing the DB to the internet directly, even with IP whitelisting. And more flexible - e.g. you can more easily connect mobile apps without duplicating the effort of writing DB queries, or allow 3rd parties to connect to it as well if needed.

Comment: When i make a web api and host it on an iis server. How do i connect it with the web application ? do you have a good tutorial for this ?

Comment: the application connects to the API using HTTP requests. Since you're building a _web_ API, that's the only way you _can_ connect. Depending on the scenarios, you could make the requests via your server-side PHP (for which you could use cURL, or some other options are available), or as ajax directly from the client-side browser (don't forget to enable CORS).  I don't have any specific tutorials I can link you to, but there are plenty around. Consider using an existing PHP API framework (again there are loads you can search for) to get going faster with the API side.

Comment: I think a PHP API framework will be a very good solution. Once again thank you very much for the informations.